# Class variables initialization in Python3 inheritance

Tags: python-3.x, oop, inheritance, initialization

I have a base class `A`, and two subclasses `B` and `C` inherited from `A`, There are some variables in `A` are shareable among all `A` objects, so I choose to use class variable and these class variables should only be initialized once, I can do this in `A` by explicitly test and set `A.some_var`.

The example code(explicit class name used):

```
from queue import Queue


class A:
    data_queue = None
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if A.data_queue is None:
            A.data_queue = Queue()


class B(A):
    pass


class C(A):
    pass


b = B()
c = C()

b.data_queue.put(5)
c.data_queue.get()  # Works fine
```

However, I don't think this is a good idea since class name may be changed during developing.

I also have tried `type` but in this way variables are shared among all `B` objects or `C` objects because `type(self)` return `B` or `C`.

```
from queue import Queue


class A:
    data_queue = None
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if type(self).data_queue is None:
            type(self).data_queue = Queue()


class B(A):
    pass


class C(A):
    pass


b = B()
c = C()

b.data_queue.put(5)
c.data_queue.get()  # Block
```

So, Is there a better way to initialize class variable in `A` without explicit class name?

Comment: Is there any reason you're not just initializing the class variable with `data_queue = Queue()` instead of `data_queue = None`?

Comment: @robert_x44 Yes, I can init `data_queue` with `data_queue = Queue()`, but I have another `Process` needs to be initialized, it needs some context info from the base class of `A`, if I choose to init it in class body, I still have to hard code the class name to access context info.(I can't define this `Process` in the base class of `A` for design reason)

Comment: `self.__class__.data_queue` will work. Mutable class-level state, or lazy initialization of class-level stuff from an _instance_ constructor, is generally _not_ a good idea. Initialize the queue right at the class creation time (yes, `data_queue = Queue()` in the class body), or think about other sharing mechanisms.

Comment: @9000 Yes, `data_queue = Queue()` works fine, But I have this `A.data_proc = Process(target=comsumer, args=(BaseA.context,))`, `BaseA` is a superclass of `A`, if I init `data_proc` like `data_queue`, then I still have to hard code something like `BaseA.context`, cuz `A` know nothing about its superclass at that time, which is not good.

Comment: @Time1ess: It looks like inheritance is not a convenient mechanism in this case. (Composition is almost always better.)

Comment: @9000 Yeah u'r right, I should try composition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some struggling, I figured out some solutions, though it is not so good, but it achieves my goal in some way.

**Solution 1: Use a decorator to set a reference to the class**

Example Code:

```
from queue import Queue


def cls_ref(cls):  # With this decorator, cls refs its self
    cls.cls = cls
    return cls


@cls_ref
class A:
    data_queue = None
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        cls = self.cls
        if cls.data_queue is None:
            cls.data_queue = Queue()


class B(A):
    pass

class C(A):
    pass


b = B()
c = C()

b.data_queue.put(5)
c.data_queue.get()  # Works fine
```

**Solution 2: Use lazy evaluation with qualified name**

According to the defination of `qualified name`:

> A dotted name showing the “path” from a module’s global scope to a
>   class, function or method defined in that module, as defined in PEP
>   3155. For top-level functions and classes, the qualified name is the same as the object’s name:

```
>>> class C:
...     class D:
...         def meth(self):
...             pass
...
>>> C.__qualname__
'C'
>>> C.D.__qualname__
'C.D'
>>> C.D.meth.__qualname__
'C.D.meth'
```

Example Code:

```
from queue import Queue


class LazyInit:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return globals()[self.name]


class A:
    cls = LazyInit(locals()['__qualname__'])
    data_queue = None
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        cls = self.cls
        if cls.data_queue is None:
            cls.data_queue = Queue()


class B(A):
    pass

class C(A):
    pass


b = B()
c = C()

b.data_queue.put(5)
c.data_queue.get()  # Works fine
```

Both solutions works fine with me, if there are other better solutions, please let me know. :)